# Prevent timer running twice

Tags: javascript, php, settimeout

I have a function activated by "onclick" element.

Problem is in prevent repeating, when i clicked more than once on "onclick event" to run this function is faster and faster.

I need to prevent second running of this function.
(onclick event is called from AJAX div, there cant be scripts, only in this function).

```
<script>
    function attack(target,carrier) {            
        document.getElementById(carrier).style.display = "block";

        var flighttime = 0,
            waytime = 10000,
            repeat = 50,
            loops = 0,
            xspeed = 2,
            yspeed = 3,
            maxloops = waytime/repeat;

        function repeat_targeting() {
            timer = setTimeout( repeat_targeting, repeat);

            flighttime = flighttime + repeat;
            loops = loops + 1;

            var starty = screen.width / 2,
                startx = screen.height / 2,
                x = document.getElementById(target).offsetTop-0,
                y = document.getElementById(target).offsetLeft-0,
                x1 = document.getElementById(carrier).offsetTop,
                y1 = document.getElementById(carrier).offsetLeft;

            if (x > x1) {document.getElementById(carrier).style.top = x1+xspeed+"px";};
            if (x < x1) {document.getElementById(carrier).style.top = x1-xspeed+"px";};
            if (y > y1) {document.getElementById(carrier).style.left = y1+yspeed+"px";};
            if (y < y1) {document.getElementById(carrier).style.left = y1-yspeed+"px";};

            if ( ((x-x1) < 5) && ((x1-x) < 5) && ((y1-y) < 5) && ((y-y1) < 5) ) {  //hit
                document.getElementById(target).className = document.getElementById(target).className + " targeted";
                //document.getElementById(carrier).style.left = "50%";
                //document.getElementById(carrier).style.top = "50%";
                //document.getElementById(carrier).style.opacity = "0";

                stop();

                showB2B('base=<?php echo $_basic['baseid'] ?>');
            }

            if (loops >= maxloops) { // if reached time
                stop();
            }
        }; //repeat

        function stop() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };

        repeat_targeting();
    }; 


 </script>

   <div id="someidforHTTPrequest"> // this div content is generated by ajax call on page load
     <button onclick="attack('base-<?php echo $base['id'] ?>','targeter')">lock</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: You could do *something* to remove the `click` event from the element. Don't know what without knowing how you're making it clickable in the first place.

Comment: Yeah but is the httprequest generated div, i cant put the scripts here

Comment: Can't you just do `this.onclick = null`?

Comment: <button onclick="attack('base-<?php echo $base['id'] ?>','targeter');this.onclick = 'null'">Lock Target</button>  not works

<button onclick="attack('base-<?php echo $base['id'] ?>','targeter');this.style.display = 'none'">Lock Target</button>  solving the problem, but i need after some time to try it again without refresh.

onclick="attack('base-<?php echo $base['id'] ?>','targeter');this.style.display = 'none'; setTimeout( this.style.display = 'block', 10000);" not works timer is running immediatelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this:

#### Removing the onclick eventlistener

In the onclick you can pass the button to your function by using `this`.

in the html:

```
<button onclick="attack(1, 2, this);">lock</button>
```

Then you can remove the onclick in the function

in the javascript:

```
function attack(target, carrier, button) {
    button.onclick = null;
    alert('clicked');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ts5y6/

#### Selfdestructing one use function

Or you can have the function self-destruct:

```
var attack = function (target, carrier) {
    window.attack = null;
    alert('clicked');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ts5y6/1/

#### Wrap a singleton semaphore in a hidden scope

```
(function(){
var timer = false; // singleton curried into window.attack, hidden from all other scopes.
window.attack = function () {
    if (timer) return false;
    timer = true; // lock 
    var count = 10;
    var countdown = function () {
        if (count === 0) { // the halting condition
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = false; // release lock
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = count--;
    }
    timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ts5y6/2/

Comment: @Martin, didn't notice you accepted... I have another solution somewhat more elaborate and closer to your complete problem. This makes sure just one is running *at a time*, until some condition is met, and running it is ok again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'timer' variable as a flag. Do:

```
function attack(target,carrier) {
 if(timer)
  return;
 ...
```

and clear 'timer' on stop:

```
function stop() {
 clearTimeout(timer);
 timer = null;
};
```

Comment: timer is not definted when function is startin, when i define it on function start it wil be meaningless